# Mouse sensitivity not being applied

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, windows-xp-embedded

I have two PCs, one running Windows XP SP3 and the other running Windows Embedded Standard 2009 (WES). WES is similar to Windows XP, I think.

Using TweakUI > Mouse > Mouse sensitivity, the default for the double-click sensitivity is "50". Testing this on the icon on the right (or in Control Panel > Mouse > Double-click speed), I can see that if I click on the far left of the icon, quickly move the mouse to the far right and click again (ie. a double-click spaced ~30 pixels apart) then a Windows double-click event is generated. Fine...but not what I want.

So I change the "Double-click" value in TweakUI to "2" and retest and now the clicks must be really close together to generate a double-click event. Great.

Problem is that on reboot, the value resets to "50" on the WES PC (but remains "2" on the XP box).

I found the relevant registry settings (which apply to Windows 7 and Windows 8, I think):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse]
"DoubleClickHeight"="4"
"DoubleClickWidth"="4"
```

and for the "Mouse sensitivity > Drag" setting, this is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"DragHeight"="12"
"DragWidth"="12"
```

On the WES box, the "Drag" setting is being faithfully saved, either using TweakUI or the registry...but the "Double-click" setting is resetting to "50", even though the registry continues to read "4"!

Any idea how to permanently set the double-click sensitivity to "2"?

Comment: Is it possible that this mouse has its own "driver" installed that is resetting it back to its own setting on reboot?

Comment: @w3d: I don't think so. As far as I can make out, all the other mouse settings are being saved correctly (double-click speed, mouse drag sensitivity, etc).

Comment: @w3d: Thanks! I'm busy asking the PC supplier if there is anything they can help me with here. The curious thing here is that if I set the TweakUI setting, then the HKCU registry setting gets updated. After the reboot, the HKCU setting is what I expect, but Windows is back to using a "50" sensitivity setting...is Windows getting the setting from somewhere else? Certainly looks like it.

Comment: @w3d: OK, solved! You were right. Checked more carefully, and found that the touchscreen attached to this industrial PC had put something into HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run which was stomping on the Windows settings. This article (and your comment) prompted me to check: [link]http://superuser.com/questions/153417/windows-xp-cant-remember-my-mouse-cursor-speed-settings?rq=1. If you knock up an answer about checking drivers, I will accept, but I've upvoted your comment anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem either another (mouse) "driver" or third party software is perhaps overriding the Windows settings.

As per comments:

> ...the touchscreen attached to this industrial PC had put something into HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run which was stomping on the Windows settings.